# Symfony3: Return a full JsonResponse loop

Tags: php, symfony, search, algolia

I just created a project to try Algolia search solution and it's working good, but I'm not able to return a JSON response.

Here is my code

controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/search/user/{query}", name="search_query")
 */
public function searchAction($query)
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManagerForClass(User::class);

    $users = $this->indexManager->search($query, User::class, $entityManager);

    if($users) {
        $result = $this->renderView('xxx/search_user.html.twig', [
            'users' => $users
        ]);

        return new JsonResponse(['success' => true, 'users' => [$result]]);
    }

    return new JsonResponse(['success' => false, 'users' => []]);
}
```

html:

```
{{ users[0].username }}
```

This code is working but only returning 1 user not all users, idem if I do a loop inside my twig file it will render all users but not in a good way:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei2sM.png)

Thanks for the help and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because twig creates the view on the server after the response.

I suggest you to simply create the users array directly inside the controller and remove the part of render view.

for example :

```
foreach($users as $user) {
$result[]['name'] = $user['name'];
}
```

and then use $result.

I hope it helps you, Regards

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got this error now: "Cannot use object of type AppBundle\Entity\User as array"

Comment: EDIT: Just resolved using the getter! Thanks @Alessandro